# Problem in rounding values in a web data rock pivot table

Tags: web, webdatarocks

Yesterday we noticed that several values in our web data rock pivot table were not rounded to the second digit as specified by the Format cells settings. The digits after the decimal point were much more.
Could this be some kind of bug or was it a temporary issue? I think the problem is with rounding numbers in a period. Today the problem is gone, but we are not sure if it won't happen again.

Checked our angular code. Tried to generate the same table the next day.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may have been caused by some inconsistency in the data or the report (for example, the measure name was changed in the loaded JSON or CSV). You could set the decimal places using the default formatting. This guarantees that this format is applied to each measure unconditionally:

```
"formats": [
    {
        "name": "",
        "decimalPlaces": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: This setting is already done in both the code and the table. I think the problem is with rounding in a period.                                                                                       
            "formats": [{
                "name": "formatting",
                "thousandsSeparator": " ",
                "decimalSeparator": ".",
                "decimalPlaces": 2,
                "currencySymbol": "",
                "currencySymbolAlign": "left",
                "nullValue": "",
                "textAlign": "right"
            }]
        });
    }

Comment: Note that the default format is set differently. The format with a non-empty `"name"` value can only be explicitly applied to the MeasureObject via `"format"` property.  The default format is applied to all available measures by setting its name as an empty string (`"name": ""`).